# Joda-Time DateTimeZone not comparing correctly

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

I've been working on unit tests for a project that uses Joda-Time, and I noticed that `DateTimeZone` instances that should represent the same time-zone aren't returning true on `equals`. In particular, on unit tests like these below

```java
// should be the same
DateTimeZone WAT = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(1); // GMT+01:00
DateTimeZone LAG = DateTimeZone.forID("Africa/Lagos"); // Lagos

DateTime sample = new DateTime(2017, 11, 15, 10, 50);
DateTime dtzWAT = sample.withZoneRetainFields(WAT);
DateTime dtzLAG = sample.withZoneRetainFields(LAG);

@Test public void compareZones() { assertEquals(WAT, LAG); }
@Test public void compareTimes() { assertEquals(dtzWAT, dtzLAG); }
```

both tests fail even though `Africa/Lagos` and `GMT+01:00` are the same time zone, and the two `DateTimes` represent the same instant - in fact, the two tests below confirm this

```java
// both succeed
@Test public void compareStrings() {
    assertEquals(dtzWAT.toString(), dtzLAG.toString()); 
}

@Test public void checkSameTime() { 
    assertFalse(dtzLAG.isBefore(dtzWAT)); 
    assertFalse(dtzWAT.isBefore(dtzLAG)); 
}
```

Why does this happen? Why are the two time-zone instances not equivalent, and is there anyway around this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "is there any way around this" what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @AndyTurner I need a way to make the DateTime instances equal. I know they are effectively equal, but I need this to reflect in the `equals` method.

Comment: But equal in what sense? If you want to make sure they refer to the same instant in time (same offset from Unix epoch), convert them to `Instant` using `.toInstant()`, then compare (or use `!a.isAfter(b) && !b.isAfter(a)`; or `a.compareTo(b) == 0`, but note that is inconsistent with `equals`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why does this happen

The `DateTimeZone`s are not equal: one is called `Africa/Lagos`, the other is `GMT+01:00`. It says in [the Javadoc of `DateTimeZone.equals`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

> true if equal, **based on the ID** and all internal rules

And for [`DateTime.equals`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> Compares this object with the specified object for equality based on the millisecond instant, chronology and **time zone**.

The time zones aren't equal, so the `DateTime`s aren't equal.

Maybe they are *effectively* equal, doesn't mean they *actually* are.

Note that `java.util.TimeZone` has the `hasSameRules(...)` method, which is a separate notion from equality.